# I have multiple quantity spinners that adds only to the first spinner

Tags: javascript

I have multiple quantity spinners that adds only to the first spinner even when I click on the last quantity spinner, it adds 1 to the first spinner and not the last one.

Only the first spinner works, the other spinners add values to the first spinner.

```
    <h2>Please Choose Truck:</h2>
        <div id="trucks" class="container">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">

        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          1 Ton Trucks
        </a>
      </h4> </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t">

                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight:  Bims:"></i></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h3>Fridge Truck</h3>
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                        <div class="qty">
                                            <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                            <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t"> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight:  Bims:"></i></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h3>Tractor Unit Truck</h3>
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                        <div class="qty">
                                            <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                            <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t">
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight:  Bims:"></i></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h3>Curtainsiders Truck</h3>
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                        <div class="qty">
                                            <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                            <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t"> 
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight:  Bims:"></i></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h3>Box Truck</h3>
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                        <div class="qty">
                                            <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                            <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                            <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          4 Ton Trucks
        </a>
      </h4> </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t">
                                            <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight: 3.5kg, 3.7kg  Bims: 4.8 x 2.4 x2.5"></i></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h3>Fridge Truck</h3>
                                            <form>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                            <div class="qty">
                                                <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                                <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                                <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight: 3.5kg, 3.7kg  Bims: 4.8 x 2.4 x2.5"></i></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h3>Tractor Unit Truck</h3>
                                            <form>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                            <div class="qty">
                                                <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                                <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                                <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title="Weight: 3.5kg, 3.7kg  Bims: 4.8 x 2.4 x2.5"></i></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h3>Curtainsiders Truck</h3>
                                            <form>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                            <div class="qty">
                                                <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                                <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                                <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-hover" img src="images/3.jpg" alt="2t">
                                            <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                          title="Weight: 3.5kg, 3.7kg  Bims: 4.8 x 2.4 x2.5"></i></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h3>Box Truck</h3>
                                            <form>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"> </form>
                                            <div class="qty">
                                                <input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="-" id="minus" />
                                                <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="2" max="10" size="0" id="number" />
                                                <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="+" id="plus" /> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
 </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

    //quantity JS
    function incrementValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value < 10) {
            value++;
            document.getElementById('number').value = value;
        }
    }

    function decrementValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value > 1) {
            value--;
            document.getElementById('number').value = value;
        }

}

    /* TRUCKS */
.panel-group {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 900px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.panel-default{
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;

}
.panel-title  a{
    color: #129cf3;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.panel-body i{
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 40px;
    color: #129cf3;
}

.panel-body tooltip{
    background: #000;
}

#trucks {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    color: #129cf3;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#trucks .title {
    text-align: center;
    left: 150px;
}
/* QUANTITY STARTS */
.qty {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
#number {
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
#minus {
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
#plus {
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* HORIZONTAL LINE @TRUCKS*/
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 850px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: From your description, the problem is presumably in the code you are using to attach these functions to the spinners themselves, which is not included here. Possible all spinners have same id?

Comment: I have a div class called qty for all of them

Comment: check number in document.getElementById('number')  you are passing , is the number or id of clicking element ?

Comment: Please either post a complete but minimal example of the code here or create a codepen if you want help. As I said, you have not provided the portions of your code that are relevant to the problem you are having.

Comment: Yes, all have the same ID, which means when you get by ID you always just get the first one. Also, every spinner is calling the same pair of functions, neither of which do anything to detect or differentiate their behavior based on the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your elements have the same ID, so when you are selecting at the document level, it will always return the first element. Also, your click handlers are not doing anything to adjust their behavior based on which is clicked.

If, however, you were to change your `onclick` handlers to `incrementValue(this)` and `decrementValue(this)` and use these slightly altered versions, I think you will find it works much better.

```
function incrementValue(caller) {
    var tEl = caller.parentElement.querySelector('#number');
    var value = parseInt(tEl.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (value < 10) {
        value++;
        tEl.value = value;
    }
}


function decrementValue(caller) {
    var tEl = caller.parentElement.querySelector('#number');

    var value = parseInt(tEl.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (value > 1) {
        value--;
        tEl.value = value;
    }

}
```

Please see [codepen](http://codepen.io/barry-johnson/pen/GWXgrL?editors=1010) for both working code, and an example of a *minimal* yet complete example.